# Private class not able to be a parameter in C#?

Tags: c#

I have written a player class and a public class called Experience. When I try to get the player level from 1 to 2, I use this method:

```
public static void LvlPlayer(Player player)
{
    if (player.Level != 10)
    {
        ++player.Level;
        player.Attack += 2;
    }
}
```

Here is the error message it gives me:

> `Error    1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Game.Player' is less accessible than method 'Game.Experience.LvlPlayer(Game.Player)'`

Can I do it this way and I'm just missing a piece of a puzzle, or does this not work? I am using this method as something I need to call in the main Driver Method. In that method I made an instance of the player class, and I intend to pass this in order to increment the player level attribute.

Why does this not work?

Comment: What is the access modifier of both your `Player` class and the field `Level`? public? private? protected? something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your class must be public:

```
public class Player
{
 (...)
}
```

Your class can'be less visible (internal) than the method that use it (LvlPlayer method is public), it's why the error tell you that

> 'Game.Player' is less accessible than method
>   'Game.Experience.LvlPlayer(Game.Player)'

Comment: done, I hope it's enought because I don't know how to better explain :-)

Comment: Just to be pedantic... you can only make inner classes private. Normal everyday ones can only go as far as internal.. which is also less visible than public

Comment: The compiler enforces that all public methods are actually callable. If you used an internal type, there would be no way the public caller could call your method, since they couldn't pass you an instance of a type that can't reference.